# How to manually add a plugin like Fancybox to your Rails app

Tags: plugins, fancybox, asset-pipeline, pipeline, assets

I need to add Fancybox to my Rails app.  Normally I would just use the gem and add the required lines to application.js and application.css.  However, I am using a bunch of different templates within my app, and I have to link in the stylesheets and js files manually (using <%= javascript_include_tag ... %>, for example) because some templates use some of them, and others dont.

On the gem's instructions page, it says I can add the assets into the lib/assets directory manually.  I've never done this before.  Do I need to manually copy the images into a lib/assets/images folder, and the js files into the lib/assets/javascripts folder, etc. or is there a way to put them all into one single "fancybox" folder so that they can all stay organized?

I will be adding more things like this into the app, and I dont want the images, javascripts, and stylesheet folders to just become a big mishmosh of different files from different plugins.

I hope this makes sense and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you have folder app/assets/javascript if you will put it there it will be loaded in your application.js file

With basic configuration all js files in assets are merged into one optimized file which you include in your views

If you want to understand it better I recommend you http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Same with images you can put them into app/assets/images/ styles into app/assets/stylesheets, if you will use folder names it should not be big mess.

From the other side if you want to keep them in one place you can still copy whole folder into public and you will have access to that files for example if you will put it into public/fancybox/... 
your path will be

```
localhost:3000/fancybox/fancybox.js
```

and you can load it on every page which will need that

Comment: I already knew I could do this, but this still creates a mishmosh. This plugin has like 10 images, 3 css files, and 3 js files.  I'd hate to copy and paste them into their respective folders, because down the road I wont know what images are associated with what plugin.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you correctly I edited my post and I think that that solution will suit you

Comment: thats did it.  Thanks for the quick response!